# Get the nid from current URL after the ? for views argument

Tags: views

I am adding a post to an Organic Group and I want to display a list of all posts to that group below the node add form. The url looks like this:

```
    node/add/group_post?gids[]=23
```

I want to add argument that filters the view using the group's id. How can I use the PHP to get that gid?

This is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
    $gid = htmlspecialchars($_GET["gids[]"]);
    return $gid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `$_GET['gids']` this will return you an array in PHP.
Then if there's only one nid you can make:

```
$gids = $_GET['gids'];
return $gids[0];
```

Source: [How to get PHP $_GET array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array)

Comment: That works...but you have to return the $gid...I also did it a less elegant way with:

`$gid= $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
$gid = explode("=", $gid);
return $gid[1];`

Comment: The problem of "=" is that if you have more parameter like `node/add/group_post?gids[]=23&destination=node` you'll have a problem ;) I updated my answer to put the return.